# Prove $2^N$ is uncountable or $2^N$ is equinumerous to power set of $N$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I've encounted this question many time in similar form in different books, but I still don't understand it.
In Enderton's set theory, it says:

[image: In Enderton's set theory, it says:]
I don't how this proof proved H(B) is injective and subjective.
Or in Munkres's Topology
[image]
What does the $g(n)$ exactly mean in this proof?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Enderton, the author is defining a function $H : \mathcal{P}(A) \to {}^A2$ by letting $H(B) = f_B \in {}^A2$, where $f_B : A \to 2$ is the characteristic function of $B$, for each $B \in \mathcal{P}(A)$.

The function $H$ is injective since distinct subsets have distinct characteristic functions. Explicitly, if $B \ne B'$ then either there is some $a \in B$ with $a \not \in B'$, in which case $f_B(a) = 1 \ne 0 = f_{B'}(a)$, or there is some $a \in B'$ with $a \not \in B$, in which case $f_B(a) = 0 \ne 1 = f_{B'}(a)$.

The function $H$ is surjective since each function $A \to 2$ is the characteristic function of the preimage of $1$, namely given $g : A \to 2$ we have $g = H(B)$, where $B = \{ x \in A \mid g(x) = 1 \}$.

---

In Munkres, it means exactly what it says: $g(n)$ is the result of applying the function $g : \mathbb{Z}^+ \to X^{\omega}$ to the element $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$. Note that since the codomain of $g$ is $X^{\omega}$ we have $g(n) \in X^{\omega}$, so $g(n)$ is itself an $\omega$-sequence of elements of $X$. The author has then chosen to express the terms of $g(n)$ by writing $g(n) = (x_{n1}, x_{n2}, \dots)$; in other words, $x_{nk}$ is the $k^{\text{th}}$ term of the sequence $g(n)$.

Comment: I think I may have some misunderstanding about definition of $2^A$. It should be a set of function from A to 2, right? But the domain of H is B which is in A, but the range of H is just 0 or 1, I think the domain of H should identical to $2^A$, which are bunch of functions. Where I am wrong?

Comment: You're correct that $2^A$ (or ${}^A2$) is the set of functions $A \to 2$. The domain of $H$ is not $B$. The domain of $H$ is $\mathcal{P}(A)$, which is the set of all subsets of $A$. It just so happens that the values of $H$ are themselves functions (since they're elements of ${}^A2$), so $H(B)$ is a function $A \to 2$ for each $B \in \mathcal{P}(A)$.

Comment: Or in short: $H$ is a function $\mathcal{P}(A) \to {}^A2$, and $H(B)$ is a function $A \to 2$ for each $B \in \mathcal{P}(A)$, since $H(B)$ is an element of ${}^A2$.

Comment: I do not sure I know what the value of H are themselves functionmean.
And in the Munkres, should $X^w$ also function? why here becomes sequence? (Sorry for the terrible type as I typed on the phone)

Comment: To the  proposer: $H$ is a function. The domain of $H$ is the Power-Set of $A$. The range of $H$ is a set of functions, namely the set of characteristic functions of subsets of $A$. Note that  a function $f_B$ can be considered to be a single object,  so the function $H$ maps the set $B$ to the object $f_B.$ That is, $H(B)=f_B.$..... To  a set-theorist, everything is a set, and a function is defined to be equal to  "its graph".

Comment: Thanks @DanielWainfleet Clive Newstead, I see why H is subjective and injective now. But I still don't know why Munkres written g(n) as that. Should the domain of g also functions? I cannot see why ($x_1$, $x_2$, ...) here is a function.

Comment: @Cathy A sequence in $X$ is exactly the same thing as a function $\mathbb N\to X.$ Just write the sequence elements like $x(n)$ rather than $x_n.$

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Thanks. I think I'm understood now. Just what to make sure, is that "a sequence in X is exactly the same thing as a function ℕ→X" because we defined sequence as function whose domain is N?

Comment: @Cathy: Yes. Sequences of elements of $X$, and functions $\mathbb{N} \to X$, are two different (but equivalent) descriptions of the same thing.

Comment: What Munkres means by $g(n)=(x_{1n},x_{n2},x_{n3},...)$  is that $g(1)=x_{n1}, g(2)=x_{n2}, g(3)=g_{n3},$ etc... I hadn't noticed that this could be confusing.....BTW it's "surjective" not "subjective". (Maybe just a typo of yours? Like "sunset" for "subset"?)

Comment: @DanielWainfleet: That's not true. It means that $g(n)(1) = x_{n1}, g(n)(2) = x_{n2}$ and so on, where we're considering $g(n)$ as a function $\omega \to X$ rather than a sequence of elements of $X$.

Comment: @CliveNewstead. Yes. You are right.  I got a little careless with the notation.